# XmlSerializer 'Compiling JScript/CSharp scripts is not supported'

Tags: c#, .net, xmlserializer

I am intending to serialise a two dimensional array. As recommended [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/dfd587ec-a269-49a9-a1a5-0f69d915c776/multidimensional-array-xml-serialization-help?forum=csharpgeneral) to provide it as a jagged array, and compose it back from a jagged array:

```cs
        [XmlIgnore]
        public Rational[,] tab;

        public Rational[][] Data
        {
            get 
            {
                Rational[][] dt = new Rational[tab.GetLength(0)][];
                for (int i = 0; i < tab.GetLength(0); i++)
                {
                    dt[i] = new Rational[tab.GetLength(1)];
                    for (int j = 0; j < tab.GetLength(1); j++)
                        dt[i][j] = tab[i, j];
                }
                return dt;
            }
            set
            {
                tab = new Rational[ value.Length, value[0].Length ];
                for (int i = 0; i < tab.GetLength(0); i++)
                    for (int j = 0; j < tab.GetLength(1); j++)
                        tab[i, j] = value[i][j];
            }
        }
```

The type `Rational` represents a fraction that can be in decimal **float** or **a/b** integers fraction format. I did separate serialisation for `Rational`, and it has no problem with this type.
I get this exception in the place where XmlSerializer is constructed:
[image]
It is thrown exactly in this place:

```
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SistemEcuatii));
```

And here is the code containing the serializer

```cs
    class SistemEcuatiiModel
    {
        string baza;
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(SistemEcuatii));
        SistemEcuatii data;
        public void WriteTo()
        {
            TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter(baza);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, data);
            writer.Close();
        }
        void LoadFromFile()
        {
            StreamReader streamer = new StreamReader(baza);
            SistemEcuatii dt = (SistemEcuatii)serializer.Deserialize(streamer);
            streamer.Close();
            data = dt;
        }
```

Searching similar info on internet did not provide some useful information:
[net-core-3-1-soap-platform-not-supported-error-compiling-jscript-csharp-script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60976792/net-core-3-1-soap-platform-not-supported-error-compiling-jscript-csharp-script)
[Docs dot microsoft dot com](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/449048/xslt-compile-error-platformnotsupportedexception-c.html)
I tried suggestion from [github issues](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2219), but still can't make it working

Comment: I faced with the same issue recently and would suggest you to create XML with the desired structure and then push it to the XSD tool (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/xml-schema-definition-tool-xsd-exe). This tool will create XSD for your XML and also generate classes you can use for your task.

Answer (score 4):

The suggestion from [github issues](https://github.com/dotnet/wcf/issues/2219) works, no need to worry about that

```
        [XmlArrayItemAttribute(typeof(Rational[]))]
        public Rational[][] Data
        {
            get 
            {
```